# Can I selectively inherit a class depending upon a boolean field?

Tags: c#, class

I am experimenting with classes and was wondering if it is possible to link classes depending on a boolean value within one of the classes. I have a Person class and a field is private 'boolean value HasPet'. So if a person has a pet then I would like for a pet object to be made and link the classes together. Is this possible. I am completely new to classes. Would I have to make an ID field and link them like that?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person Teacher = new Person("Phoebe", 32, "brown", "hazel", true);
    }
       

      public class Person
   {
    private string Name;
    private int Age;
    private string HairColour;
    private string EyeColour;
    private bool HasPet;

    public Person(string name, int age, string hairColour, string eyeColour, bool hasPet)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        HairColour = hairColour;
        EyeColour = eyeColour;
        HasPet = hasPet;
    }
     public void ChangePetStatus()
    {
        Console.Write($"We heard that your pet status has changed...");

        if (HasPet == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("we are sorry to hear that. Pet status has been changed.");
            HasPet = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("that's great. A pet is a lovely addition to the household. Pet status has been changed.");
            HasPet = true;
        }
    }


    public void Greetings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello my name is {Name} and I am {Age} years old. I have {HairColour} hair and {EyeColour} eyes. It is {HasPet} that I have a pet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "link together".  I think it would make sense to have a `List<Pet>` objects as a field in your `Person` `class`. I guess when someone calls `ChangePetStatus` you could create a new `Pet` `object` and store it in the `List<Pet>` field.

Comment: You might want to give your Person class another property/field of type Pet and in case create a Pet object and attach it to that property/field. Or phrased differently in your wording. You have fields already like name. So you have "linked" a string to the Person class. Just do the same for the Pet class.

Comment: Ah ok. I like that a person could have a list of pets as opposed to my initial 1. If I had a new field 'Pet' in the Person class which was a list how could I create a pet object and put in into the list?

Comment: Just create an instance of it: `var newPet = new Pet("Fluffy, the dog");`, then add it: `list.Add(newPet)`.

Comment: I've added 'public List<Pet> Pets;' as a field in the Person class. Then under ChangePetStatus() I have 'var newPet = new Pet("fluffy", "dog", 1, "black", "red");' and '                 Pets.Add(newPet);'. This returns a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error.

Comment: Sorry changed   public List<Pet> Pets = new List<Pet>(); to 'public List<Pet> Pets = new List<Pet>();' to remove arror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to reevaluate what inheritance means, if we look into Microsoft's definition

> Inheritance is one of the fundamental attributes of object-oriented
> programming. **It allows you to define a child class that reuses
> (inherits), extends, or modifies the behavior of a parent class**. The
> class whose members are inherited is called the base class. The class
> that inherits the members of the base class is called the derived
> class.

In your case I would say that inheritance has nothing to do with `Person` and the referred `Pet` class as neither of them will be inheriting or reusing each other's members, if you or the task insists on using inheritance for this case you'll need some other class that groups `Person` and `Pet` by similar properties for example `LivingBeing` which could have functions `Respire()`, `Move()` etc..

I would say make a many to many relationship(or one to many, if it's a specific case and `Pet` can't have more than one `Person` as owner), where `Person` could have many `Pet`s and `Pet` could have many `Person`s as owners.

classes which I would suggest are:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string HairColour { get; set; }
    public string EyeColour { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PersonPet> PersonPets { get; set; }
}

public class PersonPet
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int PetId { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PersonPet> PetPersons { get; set; }
}
```

Where you would not need any inheritance or `HasPet` field as you can determine whether `Person` has a `Pet` or not by `PersonPets`.

EDIT:
As suggested in subcomments by @Ralf this is a relational view on current problem and classes could be subject to change. The main point is that, to link Person and Pet, using inheritance is not a right way. At least in the context which author provided

Comment: BTW access modifiers to properties/fields can be changed depending on your projects needs

Comment: Thats a pretty relational view on things that belong to circumstances where a database is actually involved. Here its just blurs how things can reference each other. It would be way easier to understand if Person just uses a list of pets and pets have a list of person and forget about a "mapping class".

Comment: Yes of course, as said it's just a suggestion and not a direct answer as we don't really know  anything about the project, main point is that for linking Person and Pet using inheritance is not a right way in given context